# Postgres complicated sql query

Tags: sql, postgresql

Have a bit of a complicated query I am trying to work out.  And I'm not really sure how to query google on it to get some help...

I have a table something like this:

```
 Date      | period | meter   | value
2017-01-01 |    1   | meter01 | 1.12
2017-01-01 |    2   | meter01 | 2.12
.
.
2017-01-01 |    1   | meter02 | 0.12
2017-01-01 |    2   | meter02 | 7.12
.
.
2017-01-02 |    1   | meter01 | 2.12
2017-01-02 |    2   | meter01 | 4.12
.
.
```

There are 48 periods for any given date.  There could be hundreds of meters for any given date also.

I wish to return a result that looks something like this:

```
 Date       |  Meter    |  Period 1 | Period 2 | Period 3 | Period 4
2017-01-01  |  meter01  |    1.24   |   2.12      
2017-01-01  |  meter02  |    2.24   |   3.12
```

The result would give me the totals for each meter, date and period where the period columns are the sum of all readings for the given meter, period and date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is conditional aggregation:

```
select date, meter,
       sum(case when period = 1 then value end) as period_01,
       sum(case when period = 2 then value end) as period_02,
       sum(case when period = 3 then value end) as period_03,
       sum(case when period = 4 then value end) as period_04
from t
group by date, meter
order by date, meter;
```

Comment: Thanks so much! 

By the way... Do you know how I would round the results to 2dp?  The columns are numeric(20,8)

Comment: Hi Gordon,  would you also know how I could put the sum of all period columns for each row as the last column?  e.g.  Date       |  Meter    |  Period 1 | Period 2 | Period 3 | Period 4 | TOTAL

Comment: You would just add `sum(value) as TOTAL` for the last column in the `SELECT`.

Comment: Is it possible to make it a sum of all the case statements?  The reason being is I have rounded all the case statements to 2dp and now the totals are out if I do it that way.

Comment: And just to make it worse...  There are two days a year where the number of periods changes due to daylight savings.  Is there a way to accommodate for this?  e.g. one day will have 46 readings, and the other will have 50.  On these days it must have the exact number of columns i.e. i cannot have 50 period columns for a date that only has 48 periods.  Then there needs to be a column at the end with the sum of all period columns which all need to be rounded to 2dp.